# Achieve site specific TOR exit nodes

Tags: tor, tor-browser-bundle

Any one who's had enough experience using TOR (browser) and is persistent and adamant enough to continue to do so to regain a little of their privacy and anonymity on the internet knows that this could start becoming very challenging for many sites that automatically become the white knight in shining armor to "protect" your account from being compromised.

The technically aware cannot choose to take responsibility of their own security and need to be baby-sat along with the masses.

That being said, in order to prevent the security alarms and algorithms employed by such sites and services it may be required to force an exit node to be used from a particular region consistently, thereby satisfying one of the major triggers employed by such algorithms.

Given however, one would access a varied number of sites in a session, this poses the problem that some services are better accessed from one region and another from another region.

*Thus the question is, is there a way to configure TOR Browser to choose site specific exit nodes?*